# Call to a member function update() on null [LARAVEL]

Tags: php, database, laravel, sqlite

I am trying to make a Laravel application that allows a logged-in user to edit one of their memorial pages. The edit view works, but as soon as the changes are saved, it throws a **Call to a member function update() on null** error. I am new to **Laravel**, so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

**Controller:**

```
public function edit(Memorial $memorial)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $memorial);

    return view('memorials.edit', compact('memorial'));
}

public function update(Memorial $memorial)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $memorial);

    $data = request()->validate([
        'fname' => 'required',
        'lname' => 'required',
        'bio' => '',
    ]);

    auth()->user()->memorial->update($data);

    return redirect("/memorial/{$memorial->id}");
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="container pt-5">
<form action="/memorial/{{ $memorial->id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <legend>Edit Memorial</legend>
    @csrf
    @method('PATCH')
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <input id="fname" type="text" class="form-control @error('fname') is-invalid @enderror" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" value="{{ old('fname') ?? $memorial->fname }}" autofocus>

                @error('fname')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input id="lname" type="text" class="form-control @error('lname') is-invalid @enderror" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" value="{{ old('lname') ?? $memorial->lname }}">

                @error('lname')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <input id="bio" type="text" class="form-control @error('bio') is-invalid @enderror" name="bio" placeholder="Biography" value="{{ old('bio') ?? $memorial->bio }}">

                @error('bio')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Policy:**

```
/**
 * Determine whether the user can update the memorial.
 *
 * @param  \App\User  $user
 * @param  \App\Memorial  $memorial
 * @return mixed
 */
public function update(User $user, Memorial $memorial)
{
    return $user->id == $memorial->user_id;
}
```

Comment: The user has no memorial either data is bad or the relationship is setup wrong

Comment: This is in my User.php: public function memorials()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Memorial::class);
    }

Comment: does memorial row has the correct id or soft deleted?

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "memorial row"? The memorial row in the database? Also, users can have multiple memorials. Currently, I have 1 test user and 1 test memorial linked to that user. The test user id=1 and the memorial id=1. The memorial and the user are linked by the user_id, as shown in the policy I created above.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relation is incorrect...You don't have **memorial** relation in User model. So it returns null

You can easily edit one memorial as below code:

```
public function update(Memorial $memorial)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $memorial);

    $data = request()->validate([
        'fname' => 'required',
        'lname' => 'required',
        'bio' => '',
    ]);

    $memorial->update($data);

    return redirect("/memorial/{$memorial->id}");
}
```

because in authorize you check the privacy when you edit $memorial that is what you need

Comment: This is in my User.php: public function memorials() { return $this->hasMany(Memorial::class); }

Comment: @JakeScervino yes you have memorials... don't have memorial, and you use memorial as relation

Comment: @JakeScervino I add correct code. I hope it helps you

Comment: So you're saying I need to change 'public function memorials()' in my User model to 'public function memorial()' instead?

Comment: @JakeScervino This is back to your strategy. How many memoirs each user has? but without relation you can handle your problem. Just update $memorial object that you get as input of your update function

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that may be causing this error.  I think the first place to investigate is on your relationship vs. what you are trying to update.

**Your User model** has many memorials:

```
 public function memorials(){
     return $this->hasMany(Memorial::class);
}
```

**Your controller** is trying to update one memorial:

```
auth()->user()->memorial->update($data);
```

To fix, I suggest you try to directly update the memorial in question, rather than through the user relationship.  I assume there is a `user_id` key on the memorial - just add that in as you update the memorial that you have already injected into the update method.

Comment: The user has many memorials but is only trying to update a single one. When I use auth()->user()->memorials()->update($data), it updates the data for every memorial the user has, which is not the desired effect. I want the user to update the data for a single memorial.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense.  See the bottom part of my answer - you don't need to update through the relationship.  Use the memorial you have injected in to the method and update that model *directly*.  By adding the `user_id`, it will be attached to the user as desired. This will only update the *one* memorial as you want.

Answer (score 1):

so I see the reason is:
in User model you define the memory relation:

```
public function memorials() 
{ 
return $this->hasMany(Memorial::class); 
}
```

in function update() you call:
    auth()->user()->memorial->update($data); 
 you are calling a model, and it has proposed to get property of Memorial model.

you need to call like this:
in function update():

auth()->user()->memorials()->update($data)

in User model

```
/**
 * Eloquent：User
 *
 * //relation
 * @property Collection|Memorial[] $memorials
 */
class User extends Model
```

Comment: The user has many memorials but is only trying to update a single one. When I use auth()->user()->memorials()->update($data), it updates the data for every memorial the user has, which is not the desired effect. I want the user to update the data for a single memorial.

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I am looking for: auth()->user()->memorials($memorial['id'])->update($data); ---- (except that updates the data every memorial for that user).

Comment: you can add memorial_id into it by where().
auth()->user()->memorials()->where(memorial_id, $memorial_id)->update($data)
it is like @MohammadHosseini suggest

Answer (score 0):

**Provided you've set your relationships correctly**

Means that your had no memorial at all, i.e no memorial record which linked to that user_id, so nothing to update, thats what we say that relationship is `null` means its not existing.

You would never know if user have a relationship to memorial record or not so the trick is to create it if its not existing, or updating it if it exists with below simple eloquent code

```
auth()->user()->memorial->updateOrCreate($data);
```